# Unable to install watchman on OSX Catalina

Tags: openssl, homebrew, macos-catalina

Running the following command from my terminal :

```
brew install watchman
```

results in the following error:

```
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/openssl%401.1-1.1.1j.catalina.bottle.tar.gz

curl: (35) error:1400410B:SSL routines:CONNECT_CR_SRVR_HELLO:wrong version number
Error: Failed to download resource "openssl@1.1"
Download failed: https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/openssl%401.1-1.1.1j.catalina.bottle.tar.gz
```

I have also tried running the following command but get the same error.

```
brew install openssl@1.1
```

Any help would be appreciated